# como puedo agregar el evento de click dentro de un loop?

Tags: javascript, json, bucle-for, click

estoy trabajando en un codigo que usa un loop para recorrer un json que tiene la informacion de todo un arbol de carpetas, la idea es que la info se pinte en una tabla con enlaces y que a medida que los clickeas la tabla muestre lo que contiene adentro cada enlace (carpeta)

esto es lo que tengo, y funciona pero no logro meterle el click a los  para que ejecuten la misma funcion con el children de cada json

```
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let app = document.querySelector('#app');
let i = 0;
let resultado;
app.innerHTML = '';
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  traerdatos2();
});
//traigo el archivo y lo paso a json
function traerdatos2() {
  let dir = "../js/resultado.json"
  fetch(dir)
    .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
    .then(arbol => {
      procesar(arbol);
    });
}
//esta es una funcion para procesar el json en la tabla

function procesar(arbol) {
  arbol.children.forEach(item => {
    //recontruyo la tabla
    app.innerHTML += `
<tr>
  <th><a onclick = "" id= "${item.name}" href="#">${item.name}</a></td>
  <th><a id= "" href="#">${Math.round((item.size) / 1024)} KB</a></td>
  <th><a id= "" href="#">${item.type}</a></td>
</tr>`;
    //una ves construida quiero ponerle un click a cada <a>nombre</a> que ejecute de nuevo procesar();
    console.log(item);
    let link = document.getElementById(item.name);
    console.log(link);
    link.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('click');
    // el unico que me funciona es el ultimo click 
    });
  });
}
```

aca dejo el Json para que se entienda

```
{
    "path": "../content",
    "name": "content",
    "children": [
        {
            "path": "..\\content\\marketing",
            "name": "marketing",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "..\\content\\marketing\\bob.txt",
                    "name": "bob.txt",
                    "size": 0,
                    "extension": ".txt",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "path": "..\\content\\marketing\\Javier_Cossio01-12-19.pdf",
                    "name": "Javier_Cossio01-12-19.pdf",
                    "size": 361242,
                    "extension": ".pdf",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "size": 361242,
            "type": "directory"
        },
        {
            "path": "..\\content\\pagos",
            "name": "pagos",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "..\\content\\pagos\\cacu.txt",
                    "name": "cacu.txt",
                    "size": 0,
                    "extension": ".txt",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "path": "..\\content\\pagos\\carpetapagos",
                    "name": "carpetapagos",
                    "children": [],
                    "size": 0,
                    "type": "directory"
                }
            ],
            "size": 0,
            "type": "directory"
        },
        {
            "path": "..\\content\\ventas",
            "name": "ventas",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "..\\content\\ventas\\carpeta ventas",
                    "name": "carpeta ventas",
                    "children": [],
                    "size": 0,
                    "type": "directory"
                },
                {
                    "path": "..\\content\\ventas\\Nuevo documento de texto (2).txt",
                    "name": "Nuevo documento de texto (2).txt",
                    "size": 0,
                    "extension": ".txt",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "path": "..\\content\\ventas\\texto de ventas.txt",
                    "name": "texto de ventas.txt",
                    "size": 0,
                    "extension": ".txt",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "size": 0,
            "type": "directory"
        }
    ],
    "size": 361242,
    "type": "directory"
}
```

y el html donde aparece esto es

```
<div >
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Tamaño</th>
    <th>Fecha de creacion</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="app">
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

solo me falta saber como hago para que quede el evento, pido disculpas si no redacte correctamete el post, es la primera ver que publico en esta pagina. Agradeceria mucho una mano porque ya se me quemaron los papeles.

Comment: Que es btn en el html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
json = {
        "path": "../content",
        "name": "content",
        "children": [{
                "path": "..\\content\\marketing",
                "name": "marketing",
                "children": [{
                        "path": "..\\content\\marketing\\bob.txt",
                        "name": "bob.txt",
                        "size": 0,
                        "extension": ".txt",
                        "type": "file"
                    },
                    {
                        "path": "..\\content\\marketing\\Javier_Cossio01-12-19.pdf",
                        "name": "Javier_Cossio01-12-19.pdf",
                        "size": 361242,
                        "extension": ".pdf",
                        "type": "file"
                    }
                ],
                "size": 361242,
                "type": "directory"
            },
            {
                "path": "..\\content\\pagos",
                "name": "pagos",
                "children": [{
                        "path": "..\\content\\pagos\\cacu.txt",
                        "name": "cacu.txt",
                        "size": 0,
                        "extension": ".txt",
                        "type": "file"
                    },
                    {
                        "path": "..\\content\\pagos\\carpetapagos",
                        "name": "carpetapagos",
                        "children": [],
                        "size": 0,
                        "type": "directory"
                    }
                ],
                "size": 0,
                "type": "directory"
            },
            {
                "path": "..\\content\\ventas",
                "name": "ventas",
                "children": [{
                        "path": "..\\content\\ventas\\carpeta ventas",
                        "name": "carpeta ventas",
                        "children": [],
                        "size": 0,
                        "type": "directory"
                    },
                    {
                        "path": "..\\content\\ventas\\Nuevo documento de texto (2).txt",
                        "name": "Nuevo documento de texto (2).txt",
                        "size": 0,
                        "extension": ".txt",
                        "type": "file"
                    },
                    {
                        "path": "..\\content\\ventas\\texto de ventas.txt",
                        "name": "texto de ventas.txt",
                        "size": 0,
                        "extension": ".txt",
                        "type": "file"
                    }
                ],
                "size": 0,
                "type": "directory"
            }
        ],
        "size": 361242,
        "type": "directory"
    };

    let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
    let app = document.querySelector('#app');
    let i = 0;
    let resultado;
    app.innerHTML = '';

    /*btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      traerdatos2();
    });
    //traigo el archivo y lo paso a json
    function traerdatos2() {
      let dir = "../js/resultado.json"
      fetch(dir)
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
        .then(arbol => {
          procesar(arbol);
     });
    }*/


    // validar hijos
    function getpath(parent) {
        // recorremos el json
        for (let x in json.children) {
            //si el padre es igual al hijo del json
            if (json.children[x].path === parent) {
                // retornamos los hijos de los hijos
                return json.children[x];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    //esta es una funcion para procesar el json en la tabla
    function procesar(arbol) {
        //let app = '';
        app.innerHTML = "";

        arbol.children.forEach(item => {
            //recontruyo la tabla
            app.innerHTML += `
    <tr>
    <th><a  id="path" href="#" data-path="${item.path}">${item.name}</a></td>
    <th><a id="" href="#">${Math.round((item.size) / 1024)} KB</a></td>
    <th><a id="" href="#">${item.type}</a></td>
</tr>`;
            //una ves construida quiero ponerle un click a cada <a>nombre</a> que ejecute de nuevo procesar();

        });

        //let link = document.getElementById(item.name);

        // seleccionamos los tr th a con id path
        // y hacemos un loop
        for (x of document.querySelectorAll('tr th a[id="path"]')) {
            // agregamos un evento click a cada a
            x.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                // verificamos que tenga hijos
                let childrens = getpath(e.target.dataset.path);
                // si tiene hijos
                if (childrens) {
                    // llamamos a procesar con la data de los hijos
                    procesar(childrens);
                }
                // el unico que me funciona es el ultimo click
            });
        }
    }

    procesar(json);
```

```html
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Tamaño</th>
                    <th>Fecha de creacion</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="app">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: no lo habia pensado asi, graias bro! me re sirvio

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente es porque el `innerHTML +=` está 'matando' a los otros listeners porque sobreescribe todo el html. Intenta formar el html y agregarlo trozo por trozo.
Por ejemplo

```
newRow = document.createElement('tr');
newRow.innerHTML = `
    <th><a onclick = "" id= "${item.name}" href="#">${item.name}</a></td>
    <th><a id= "" href="#">${Math.round((item.size) / 1024)} KB</a></td>
    <th><a id= "" href="#">${item.type}</a></td>`
newRow.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', console.log('hola'));
//querySelector devuelve el primer elemento encontrado por el selector. 
//Como el <a> que contiene el id es el primero, no es necesario 
//agregar nada más al selector
app.append(newRow);
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias es como decias, el `innerHTML +=` me reseteaba todo! gracias!

Comment: Por nada. Sólo como comentario, el código de la otra respuesta funciona con dos ciclos, de modo que primero se recorren los datos para generar el html y luego se recupera y recorre el html para asignar el listener, mientras que en este, se asigna el listener desde antes de insertar el html, de modo que es un sólo ciclo.